# Tried factory resetting computer, crashed

Tags: 12.04, wubi

I have an **ASUS EEEPC 1201ha**, with **Windows 7** starter, and **Ubuntu 12.04** lts via **Wubi**.

I tried to factory reset it, but when I did, it started saying **BOOTMGR** is missing, and now it only shows a blinking cursor (underscore), when I turn it on. I've factory resetted it before, and this is the first this has happened, could it have something to do with **Wubi** being installed whilst I tried to reset it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it has nothing to do with Wubi. Wubi installs Ubuntu as a software in windows 7. If your factory reset is done and still its saying BOOTMGR missing then you can  use a windows 7 repair disc or windows 7 live usb or live cd

boot from any of the above windows disc and go to repair but not to use startup repair instead repair using windows command prompt

type the following two commands in cmd exactly

Bootrec/fixmbr 'press enter'

Bootrec/fixboot 'press enter'

now reboot u can see windows boot loader again.

or

if you can get windows repair disc or os disc or live usb then use factory reset again it may solve your problem